# Converting Scala OOP code to Functional code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming

I'm following some Spark tutorials and to my dismay it appears as though the lecturer is not following Scala's best practices. He uses var and state changes whereas I would prefer to work with immutable data; so I changed my code to better fit the functional paradigm, however as I'm still new to the language I'm not 100% my code is equivalent.

The code is essentially suppose to loop from 1 through 10. Every iteration it conducts a `.flatMap()` operation on an RDD and checks to see if a `LongAccumulator` has reached a certain value. If it has reached this value, then it breaks the loop, otherwise it executes `.reduceByKey()` on the RDD then begins the next iteration.

A few things I'm not sure of:

1. If my implementation of the LongAccumulator is correct (I try incrementing it by passing it into a function) : **In my map function**
2. Do I have to store the results of a function (such as `.flatMap()` on an `RDD` in a new `val` or will simply calling `rdd.flatMap()` store the results in a new memory address and point the prexisting `val rdd` to the new memory address (in a similar fashion to the work flow of immutable `Vectors`) : **In my for loop**

For those wondering, this is an implementation of a breadth first search algorithm on a graph constructed from a `.txt` file. Where the lecturer has opted to use colors, I used numbers from 1-3 to simplify code later on. I've also chosen to use `Vectors` over `Arrays`.

## Initialising variables:

```
//My code, outside main class


type NodeMetaData = (Vector[Int], Int, Int)
type Node = (Int, NodeMetaData)

//Within main class


val sparkContext = new SparkContext("local[*]", "TestContext")

val hitCounter = sparkContext.longAccumulator("counter")



//Tutorial code, outside main class


// We make our accumulator a "global" Option so we can reference it in a 
mapper later.
var hitCounter:Option[LongAccumulator] = None

// Some custom data types 
// BFSData contains an array of hero ID connections, the distance, and 
color.
type BFSData = (Array[Int], Int, String)
// A BFSNode has a heroID and the BFSData associated with it.
type BFSNode = (Int, BFSData)


//Within main class


val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "DegreesOfSeparation") 

// Our accumulator, used to signal when we find the target 
// character in our BFS traversal.
hitCounter = Some(sc.longAccumulator("Hit Counter"))
```

## My for loop:

```
val normalisedValues = graphText.map(x => parseLine(x, 5306)) //rdd
breakable {
      for (n <- 1 to 10) {
        println("Running bfs iteration#"+n)
        normalisedValues.flatMap(x => mapBfs(x, 14, hitCounter))
        println("Processing " + normalisedValues.count() + " values\n")

        if (hitCounter.isRegistered) {
          if (hitCounter.value > 0) {
            println("Found target from " + hitCounter.value + "different directions")
            break
          } else {
            normalisedValues.reduceByKey(reduceBfs)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

## Tutorial for loop:

```
var iterationRdd = createStartingRdd(sc)
var iteration:Int = 0
    for (iteration <- 1 to 10) {
      println("Running BFS Iteration# " + iteration)

      // Create new vertices as needed to darken or reduce distances in the
      // reduce stage. If we encounter the node we're looking for as a GRAY
      // node, increment our accumulator to signal that we're done.
      val mapped = iterationRdd.flatMap(bfsMap)

      // Note that mapped.count() action here forces the RDD to be evaluated, and
      // that's the only reason our accumulator is actually updated.  
      println("Processing " + mapped.count() + " values.")

      if (hitCounter.isDefined) {
        val hitCount = hitCounter.get.value
        if (hitCount > 0) {
          println("Hit the target character! From " + hitCount + 
              " different direction(s).")
          return
        }
      }

      // Reducer combines data for each character ID, preserving the darkest
      // color and shortest path.      
      iterationRdd = mapped.reduceByKey(bfsReduce)
    }
  }
```

## My map function:

```
def mapBfs(node:Node, targetId:Int, counter: LongAccumulator): Vector[Node] = {
    val relations = node._2
    val results:Vector[Node] = Vector.empty[Node]
    if(relations._2 == 2) {
      relations._1.foreach(x => {
        if (x == targetId) {
          if (counter.isRegistered) counter.add(1) else None
        }
        results :+ (x, (Vector(), counter.value.toInt, 2))

      })

    }

    results :+ (node._1, (relations._1, relations._2, if(relations._2 == 2) 3 else 2))
  }
```

## Tutorial map function:

```
/** Expands a BFSNode into this node and its children */
  def bfsMap(node:BFSNode): Array[BFSNode] = {

    // Extract data from the BFSNode
    val characterID:Int = node._1
    val data:BFSData = node._2

    val connections:Array[Int] = data._1
    val distance:Int = data._2
    var color:String = data._3

    // This is called from flatMap, so we return an array
    // of potentially many BFSNodes to add to our new RDD
    var results:ArrayBuffer[BFSNode] = ArrayBuffer()

    // Gray nodes are flagged for expansion, and create new
    // gray nodes for each connection
    if (color == "GRAY") {
      for (connection <- connections) {
        val newCharacterID = connection
        val newDistance = distance + 1
        val newColor = "GRAY"

        // Have we stumbled across the character we're looking for?
        // If so increment our accumulator so the driver script knows.
        if (targetCharacterID == connection) {
          if (hitCounter.isDefined) {
            hitCounter.get.add(1)
          }
        }

        // Create our new Gray node for this connection and add it to the results
        val newEntry:BFSNode = (newCharacterID, (Array(), newDistance, newColor))
        results += newEntry
      }

      // Color this node as black, indicating it has been processed already.
      color = "BLACK"
    }

    // Add the original node back in, so its connections can get merged with 
    // the gray nodes in the reducer.
    val thisEntry:BFSNode = (characterID, (connections, distance, color))
    results += thisEntry

    return results.toArray
  }
```

Comment: I think this should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @philantrovert I thought so too however my code **does not** produce the same output as the OOP code, it doesnt function properly so I feel as though it would be improper to post it on `codereview`

Comment: This question isn't fit for codereview but it is not fit on SO in it's current state. This is not a basic debugging question. You ought breaking your code down and isolating the part that is not producing the correct output.

Comment: @eliasah I pointed out the areas where I think I'm going wrong (listed 1 and 2). I added additional edits to point the code blocks in question. The rest of the code is there for context if needed

Comment: Can you please point out the link to that tutorial ?

Comment: @eliasah unfortunately the tutorial is a paid service so I can't link it, however I can provide the full tutorial code instead

Comment: I have the code thanks ! https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maciejmarczak/spark-exercises/master/src/main/scala/org/maciejmarczak/scala/DegreesOfSeparation.scala

Comment: how is the skeleton of your application ? object Main extends App by any luck or object Main { } ?

Comment: @eliasah object objectName{ def main() }

Comment: The code in that tutorial is quite bad to be honest. Not much you can salvage here.

Comment: It can’t be taken as a reference...

Comment: @eliasah indeed the reason for my attempt to rectify it aha

Comment: But you are using that code as a control code base...

Comment: You probably want to stay away from `Accumulator`s and `Accumulable`s. I believe they are mostly use for throwing in some quick code for debugging without having to dramatically restructure your code. `RDD`s are immutable, so a call to `flatMap` will create a new `RDD` without effecting the `RDD` object on which the `flatMap` method was called.

Comment: @JasonLenderman ah ok thank you, that must be where I'm going wrong

Comment: @JasonLenderman would broadcast variable work to better effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

```
type NodeMetaData = (Vector[Int], Int, Int)
  type Node = (Int, NodeMetaData)



  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val startID:Int = 5306 //Spiderman
    val targetID:Int = 14 //Adam 3031

    val sparkContext = new SparkContext("local[*]", "TestContext")

    val hitCounter = sparkContext.longAccumulator("counter")

    val nameText = sparkContext.textFile("SparkScala/Marvel-names.txt")
    val nameLookup = nameText.flatMap(mapName)
    val graphText = sparkContext.textFile("SparkScala/Marvel-graph.txt")

    var normalisedValues = graphText.map(x => createNode(x, startID)).reduceByKey((x,y) => (x._1.union(y._1),x._2,x._3))

    for(n <- 1 to 10){
      val searchables: Vector[Int] = normalisedValues.filter(_._2._3 == 3).reduce((x,y) => (0,(x._2._1.union(y._2._1),0,0)))._2._1
      val broadcast = sparkContext.broadcast(searchables)
      val currentDistance = sparkContext.broadcast(n)
      normalisedValues = normalisedValues.map(x => if(broadcast.value.contains(x._1) && x._2._3 != 3) markNode(x, currentDistance.value) else x).map(conquerNode)
    }

    val collection = normalisedValues.collect()

    collection.sortWith((x,y) => x._2._2 < y._2._2 ).foreach(x =>{
      if(x._1 == targetID) {
        println(f"${nameLookup.lookup(targetID).head} is ${x._2._2} degrees away from ${nameLookup.lookup(startID).head}")
      }
    })
  }


  def mapName(line:String): Option[(Int, String)]={
    val values = line.split(" ", 2)
    val name = values(1).replace("\"", "")
    Some(values(0).toInt, name)
  }

  def createNode(line: String, startId:Int): Node ={
    val connections = line.split("\\s+")
    val id = connections(0).toInt
    val relations = connections.map(_.toInt).filter( _ != id ).toVector
    val color = if ( id == startId ) 3 else 1
    val distance = if ( id == startId )  0 else 9999
    (id, ( relations, distance, color ))

  }

  def markNode(node:Node, distance:Int): Node ={
    (node._1,(node._2._1, distance, 2))
  }


  def conquerNode(node:Node): Node = {
    if(node._2._3 == 2) {
      (node._1, (node._2._1, node._2._2, 3))
    } else { node }
  }
```

The solution was to create 2 separate functions: a function that marked a node as gray (color == 2) and then another that that 'conquered' the node by marking it black. In order to figure out what nodes to mark as grey next; the union of the `Vectors` of all the previously marked black nodes was broadcast at the start of every loop.

One downside of this implementation was the use of `var normalisedValues`. This could have been avoided by appending new `RDDs` to the tail of a `Vector`, and simply reading the tail at the start of the next iteration however I did not want to do this as it would've resulted in significant mememory overhead if I was to store each `RDD`. However for demonstration purposes, this will do. Please refer to

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maciejmarczak/spark-exercises/master/src/main/scala/org/maciejmarczak/scala/DegreesOfSeparation.scala

to see the original code.